# SSDT add assembly to deploy

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2012, deployment, .net-assembly, sql-server-data-tools

I have old project that uses WCF from withing C# CLR triggers for SQL Server. I was always installing it by running a script.

But I've decided to move on to SSDT project on VS 2012. I've imported project from empty database. 
WCF functionality depends on several assemblies from .net framework

```
SMdiagnostics
System.Web
System.Messaging
system.identitymodel
system.identitymodel.selectors
microsoft.transactions.bridge
System.ServiceModel
```

So I have a reference to these dlls in my project. I also had them added to my project under Assemblies sub folder.

However when I create a deployment script, these assemblies are not in it.

So when I try to publish script to database I receive an error.

> Assembly 'system.servicemodel, version=3.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089.' was not found in the SQL catalog.

If I try to create custom script to add assemblies to db :

```
create assembly [SMdiagnostics]
from  'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\SMdiagnostics.dll'
with permission_set = unsafe
go
```

I receive error

> Error:  SQL70502: The assembly source is not valid. Only binary literals are allowed.

How can I add assembly from .NET to be deployed along with my SSDT project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

To add a .NET assembly to a SSDT project:

1. In Solution Explorer, expand the project and right-click References.
2. In the Add References window, either browse for the assembly or choose from the Assemblies category.
3. Right-click on the added assembly and click Properties.
4. Make sure these properties are set:

   - Generate Sql Script: True
   - Model Aware: True
   - Permission Set: Safe/External/Unsafe (depending on the assembly)
5. Press F5 to deploy to LocalDB/Debug destination or choose Publish and Generate Script to verify the changes.

DACPACs (the result of a SSDT build) doesn't allow CREATE ASSEMBLY with paths because the DLL isn't included and the path can't be guaranteed on another host. Therefore only embedded binary literals are allowed in the DACPAC.